# how to link two single container AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Multicontainer config does not work for me so - I have two docker based single container environments and need to connects them. Hosts are on the same VPC.

I could imagine how to link hosts as they are on the same VPC but I have no idea how to link together those elasticbeanstalk environments as ports are mapped to host machines

Comment: Can you please elaborate your usecase? It would be helpful to know what is your definition of connecting two environments.

Comment: usecase - redeploy app  separately from a database using an additional single container environment for a DB